# Error : Segmentation fault (core dumped) al ejecutar NestJS API en Docker

Tags: nodejs, npm, docker, nestjs, yarn

tengo una API escrita con NestJs , la cual esta envuelta en un contenedor de docker, mi archivo docker-compose.yml es el siguiente:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  dippi-api:
    image: ghcr.io/myapp/api:dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    platform: "linux/amd64"
    command: yarn workspace @myapp/api run start:debug
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./apps/:/usr/src/app/apps:z
      - ./libs/:/usr/src/app/libs:z
      - ./.yarn/:/usr/src/app/.yarn:z
    networks:
      - dippi-network
    ports:
      - 3000:3000


networks:
  myapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

, estoy utilizando una instancia EC2 de AWS con ubuntu 22 , t2.large ,vCPUs 2, 100 GB de almacenamiento.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que al ejecutar el comando 'docker compose up' para correr mi aplicacion, recibo el error : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` , sin mas explicacion , pero si ejecuto el comando : `yarn workspace @myapp/api run start:debug` manualmente , el API se ejecuta perfectamente, por lo que me hace pensar que es un tema de Docker, pero no tengo ni idea de que hacer.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.